# String into integer in C++

Tags: c++, string, integer, type-conversion

I have string value like this : `2014-04-14`

I want to convert this into Integer like this  `20140414`

i know string in to Integer can be done like this

```
std::string myString = "45";
int value = atoi(myString.c_str()); //value = 45
```

but i don't know how to remove `-` sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using streams:

```
std::istringstream iss("2014-04-14");
```

Then if you have C++11, you can use the new [`get_time` io manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time):

```
std::tm tm;
if (iss >> get_time(&tm, "%Y-%m-%d"))
    ...
```

The [`std::tm` structure](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm) has the extracted values, namely:

- years ***since 1900*** stored in `tm.tm_year`
- months ***since January*** (so 0..11) stored in `tm.tm_mon`
- day of the month (1..31) stored in `tm.tm_mday`

So, your desired value is:

```
int value = (tm.tm_year + 1900) * 10000 + (tm.tm_mon + 1) * 100 + tm.tm_mday;
```

---

Alternatively, or with C++03, you can parse the values out of the `istringstream` yourself:

```
int year, month, day;
char c;
if (iss >> year >> c && c == '-' &&
    iss >> month >> c && c == '-' &&
    iss >> day)
{
    int value = year * 10000 + month * 100 + day;
    ... use value ...
}
else
    std::cerr << "invalid date\n";
```

Comment: I like this, because the question suggests he wants to parse dates - so your answer already covers his next question :)

Comment: @Tony D. what is iss? im getting error on that. does it required any header file?

Comment: @ChrisInked Yes. Exactly :)

Comment: @IamBatman: `iss` is a `std::istringstream` - they're in the header `<sstream>`.  Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a combination of [std::remove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove/) and [std::vector#erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/):

> myString.erase(std::remove(myString.begin(), myString.end(), '-'), myString.end());

This code removes the `-`.

Comment: where should i enter this code in my program. before int value = atoi(myString.c_str()); im pretty new to C++

Answer (score 0):

The *brute force* method:

```
const std::string text_date = "2014-04-25";
std::string text_no_dash;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < text_date.length; ++i)
{
  if (text_date[i] != '-')
  {
    text_no_dash += text_date[i];
  }
}
```

This code shows the algorithm of only copying needed characters from a string to a new string.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using this? This is how i've done it in the past to remove any symbols which i didn't need.

```
char characters[] = "*()$-";

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(characters); ++i)
{
  stringName.erase (std::remove(stringName.begin(), stringName.end(), characters[i]), stringName.end());
}
```

Comment: I didnt get the correct answer for date 2014-04-10 i got the answer 32767. i think its garbage value or something.